# Nightwatch tests to work on edge

Tags: microsoft-edge, nightwatch.js

I'm trying to get nightwatch tests to work in Microsoft edge. I'm getting an error saying connection refused. What's the right configuration to get tests to work on edge? Windows 10 edge 13

Answer (score 0):

Could you post your configuration?

Make sure you have installed microsoft edge webdriver (you may download it here https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/). 
You have to specify path to your edge driver using `webdriver.edge.driver` param, ex.

    `"selenium": {
        "start_process": true,
        "server_path": "./node_modules/file_dependencies/selenium-server-standalone.jar",
        "log_path": "",
        "host": "127.0.0.1",
        "port": seleniumPort,
        "cli_args": {
            "webdriver.chrome.driver": "./node_modules/file_dependencies/chromedriver.exe",
            "webdriver.ie.driver": "./node_modules/file_dependencies/IEDriverServer.exe",
            "webdriver.edge.driver": "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Web Driver/MicrosoftWebDriver.exe",
            "webdriver.gecko.driver": "./node_modules/file_dependencies/geckodriver.exe",
            "webdriver.firefox.profile": ""
        }
}`

and example capabilities

        `"edge": {
            "desiredCapabilities": {
                "browserName": "MicrosoftEdge",
                "javascriptEnabled": true,
                "acceptSslCerts": true,
                "pageLoadStrategy": "eager"
            }
}`

Comment: Which version of edge driver are you using? Which version of selenium server?

Comment: @Jasmine - check out the Edge Driver download page - you need to match the version of your Edge Driver against the installed version of Edge.